# Python module not found since installing anaconda

Tags: python, conda

On a remote machine (of which I'm not the administrator), I have a python code that has the line:

```
import george
```

I had previously installed the george software and everything was working fine.

More recently (again on the remote machine) I did the following:

```
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit==10.0.130 tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1 keras scikit-learn pandas scipy numpy matplotlib scikit-image jupyter pyyaml=3.13
```

Since then, when I try to `import george` I just get the message:

```
No module named 'george'
```

I guess it is now looking in the wrong place or something like that. I'm confused about having different environments / versions of python / paths. Could anyone suggest how to proceed so that I can `import george` again?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the package in your conda environment using

```
conda install -c conda-forge george
```

Comment: Well that was pretty simple. Thanks!